# Wordpress symbols undefined in proxy called AJAX script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, extjs

I am working hard to populate an ExtJS data grid in my Wordpress plugin. I am totally new to web programming so the following may be a stupid question.

I managed to write a PHP script that delivers a webpage with embedded Java Sript code that creates a ExtJS data grid in the front side and sucessfully queries data using a ExtJS proxy, model and data store. That json proxy calls a separate getdata.php script (by its URL) that queries the database, converts the retrieved data to json format and returns them by echo. This works.

Now I intended to add some debugging code to the getdata.php script. Unfortunately when using `if (WP_DEBUG) {}` I get an error telling me `Use of undefined constant WP_DEBUG` (which I found out by debugging the network access since the database script is called by the proxy and does not produce visible output). In other scripts I can use the WP_DEBUG symbol without problems.

Any idea why my getdata.php doesn't know WP_DEBUG while other scripts of the plugin do?

UPDATE: Seems all the Wordpress smybols are unknown in the getdata.php.

UPDATE2: AJAX scripts need to be called using special WordPress methods. See my answer below.

Comment: set define('WP_DEBUG', false); to define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config.php to debug
More info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: I already did this (otherwise it wouldn't work in other scripts too). As I said it is only unknown in that special json script.

Comment: Try it like this:
if ( !defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) || WP_DEBUG == false )
{define('WP_DEBUG', true);}

Answer (score 2):

If you've already done what Danny suggested and it didn't work I think that may beg the question of whether or not the page itself is done as a plugin or otherwise generated from wordpress itself or if it's just a php page you wrote that happens to be in the same folder/server but that doesn't at any point include or call upon wordpress. If it's the later make sure you're including wp-load like so:

```
include('wp-load.php');
```

Comment: It actually is a plugin. The plugin provides a short code that allows embedding the mentioned ExtJS data grid into articles. And it works. Even more I wonder why I need to do a manual step (like the include you propose) to get the WP symbols. All the other scripts of the plugin do not have that problem. I suppose it has to do with the fact that the script is invoked using the data store proxy.

Comment: If it were just a php script sitting on the server or in the same folder in that case you would need the include. In your case, if I'm understanding correctly, what looks like is happening is that you're accessing the script through an ajax like request which is simply loading the php script like it were a standard file then manipulating the response. That script can't see wordpress functions or constants because it never instantiated wordpress and is functioning as a standalone script. I'm no ExtJS expert but from what I'm reading on Ext.data.Store in the manual I'd say the include may work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I have found the right way, at least in theory. Combining info from http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and http://www.wopsta.de/using-an-ext-js-datagrid-with-ajax-in-the-wordpress-administration-panel/.

However something is going wrong when testing that method... the AJAX query hook isn't called. I moved that problem to separate question to avoid confusions.